# Get Image URL in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I have the below code which allows me to get all type of document URL for SharePoint which can be opened from link but there are images when trying to open it load the same page

here is a format for URL

```
<a target='_blank'  href='"+data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a>

function getList() {        
      var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Reports')/items?$top=1000&$select=Created,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,FileLeafRef,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl&$expand=Author/Id&$filter=FSObjType eq 0";
      console.log(fullUrl);
      $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
      });
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
      var listItemInfo = " ";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
            if (data.d.results[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) { 
        listItemInfo += "<div class=panel-heading><h4><a target='_blank'  href='"+data.d.results[i].ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl+"'>"+data.d.results[i].FileLeafRef+"</a></h4><p>"+String.format("{0:d}",new Date(data.d.results[i].Created))+",&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.FirstName+"&nbsp;"+data.d.results[i].Author.LastName+"</p></div>";
            
            }  
        } 
     
        console.log(listItemInfo);
         $("#divResults").html(listItemInfo);
      };
     
     
    
    function onQueryFailed() {
      alert('Error!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research and testing, the following code can achieve the function of getting the Image URL from SharePoint document library, you can refer to :

```
function GetListItemByTitle() {
   $.ajax({ 
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test')/Items?$select=FileRef/FileRef", 
   type: "GET", 
   headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
   success: function (data) { 
      if (data.d.results) { 
         // TODO: handle the data  
         console.log(data.d.results[0].FileRef);
      } 
   }, 
   error: function (xhr) { 
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); 
   } 
}); 
}
```